# Unable to locate Element is coming for dojo page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error like:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='xwt_widget_notification_ValidationTextBox_6']"}

but the path which I mentioned is correct, the issue is my web page looks like the image which I shared.

It has got only one frame but it is a dojo page, I am able to perform all other operations except filling up the the value in the text box.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share HTML as well??

Comment: <input value="" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" id="xwt_widget_notification_ValidationTextBox_6" maxlength="32" class="dijitReset" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" type="text">

Comment: the above is the the html code, how to locate the element?

Comment: Does id attribute value dynamically changes for  this element??

Comment: yes it is changing

Comment: share then two three level above html with this element??

Comment: And in screenshot which element you want to locate??? do you wan to locate displayName text box which appears in popup dialog??

Comment: If yes, share whole HTML content for this popup dialog.

Comment: it is not allowing to post the long html code , but i tried the absolute xpath from firebug which i got , html/body/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/div/div[3]/input this is also not able to locate

Comment: i want it for text box only

Comment: It's not a stable `xpath`. you can edit your question as well and provided long HTML content, and which text box element do you want?? display name text box or something other??

Comment: ya i have attached the screen shot

Comment: Try provided answer and let me know..:)

Answer (score 0):

`id` attribute value of the element looks dynamically generated, so you should try using [`following-sibling axes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) of the `xpath` with `WebDriverWait` to wait until it's getting visible as below :-

```
WebElement textBox = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(.//td[contains(text(),'Display Name*')]/following-sibling::td)[1]//div[contains(@class, 'dijitInputField')]/input")));
```

**Edited**:- This element present inside an `iframe` with title `Universal Device Template Configuration`, try to switch that `iframe` before finding element as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[title = 'Universal Device Template Configuration']")));

//now find the desire element
WebElement textBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(.//td[contains(text(),'Display Name*')]/following-sibling::td)[1]//div[contains(@class, 'dijitInputField')]/input")));
```

Comment: This also is not able to locate the element , when i am giving the xpath which you provided in the firepath it is not able to highlight the required box

Comment: @user3388407 Did you look for `frame/iframe`?? make sure this element is not inside any `frame/iframe`

Comment: there is ony one iframe it is showing, i am not sure how to check that frame/iframe thing , this xpath also didn't work

Comment: verify with this `xpath` : `(.//td[contains(text(),'Display Name*')]/following-sibling::td)[1]//div[contains(@class, 'dijitInputField')]/input`

Comment: if `iframe` exist let me know desire element is exist in the `iframe` or not??

Comment: And if you could not check share screenshot from iframe, I want to see it

Comment: This also didn't helped

Comment: i am not sure how to check for iframe thing

Comment: execute this line on browser console `$x("//iframe")` it will return all existing `iframe` in the page then expand all `iframe` element and see if desire element present..

Comment: output came as:- [iframe#loadstatusbox, iframe]

Comment: Expand both and see if desire element existing inside..and let me know..

Comment: how to check it, can u please explain once

Comment: i think it is present in the second one :- iframe

Comment: Then could you share that second iframe HTML??

Comment: Or try provided edited answer which will switch second frame before find element, try it and let me know..:)

Comment: Ok I have provided it in edited answer, try it and let me know.

Comment: Actually the earlier HtML code which i provided was correct one only

Comment: What do you mean didn't work?? What is the exception occurred??